# error: size in array new must have integral type [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, integral, function-templates

I'm using dynamic memory allocation to create new objects and the following error keeps showing up when I try to compile. I have dimensions_ created as an unsigned int so I'm not sure why this error shows up.

```
EuclideanVector.h:69:40: error: size in array new must have integral type [-fpermissive]
                         magnitude_  =  new double [dimensions_];
```

The following is the code where the error points to:

```
// target constructor for delegating constructor
template <typename NUM1, typename NUM2> // any numeric types of user input for dimensions and magnitude will be static_cast to unsigned int and double respectively
EuclideanVector(const NUM1 dimensions, const NUM2 magnitude){

            // static cast to unsigned int for temp and assign dimensions_ to that
            unsigned int temp = static_cast<unsigned int>(dimensions);
            dimensions_ = new unsigned int (temp);

            // assign pointer "magnitude_" to dynamically-allocated memory of new unnamed array<double> object of size "dimensions_"
            magnitude_  =  new double [dimensions_];

            // fill the array<double> object "magnitude_" a number of "dimensions_" times, with the <double> value of "magnitude_" for each dimension
            std::fill_n(magnitude_, dimensions_, static_cast<double>(magnitude));

            updateNormal();
      }
```

Comment: How do you call this template?

Comment: I use a delegating constructor:

template <typename NUM>
            EuclideanVector(const NUM dimensions = 1): 
                  EuclideanVector(dimensions, 0.0) {};

Comment: There is also a warning during compiling but I think that one not as crucial, but if you can let me know how to resolve that warning will be great too:

EuclideanVector.h: In instantiation of ‘evec::EuclideanVector::EuclideanVector(NUM1, NUM2) [with NUM1 = int; NUM2 = double]’:
EuclideanVector.h:46:50:   required from ‘evec::EuclideanVector::EuclideanVector(NUM) [with NUM = int]’
EuclideanVectorTester.cpp:9:30:   required from here

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] in your question please, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `dimensions_ = new unsigned int (temp);` --- Why??  And why not just use `std::vector<double> magnitude_` and forget this whole `new[]` thing?

Comment: Hahaha it's for a school assignment. Forced to use new. =P

Comment: @iteong -- There is no excuse for using `new` here: `dimensions_ = new unsigned int (temp);`.  You've gone completely overboard if you're allocating a single `int` dynamically instead of just declaring an `int`.

Comment: So you propose declaring an int for the temp object? I just need to make sure to use "dynamic memory allocation" -_-""

Comment: @iteong -- If you use your logic, every single line should have `new` in it somewhere.  Does that make sense?  What you probably need `new` for in your school assignment is to create a dynamic **array** using `new[ ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dimensions_` is a pointer, not an `unsigned int`, returned from `new unsigned int (temp);`.
You need something like `magnitude_  =  new double [*dimensions_];`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a pointer as an array size.

A general solution for "array of size computed at run-time" is to use `std::vector`.